# ZK InputElement name attribute

Tags: java, html, zk, autofill

to use some browser's capability to "autofill" (like *"Ah, this input is called 'firstname', let me offer my user all the firstnames he entered elsewhere"*), we would like to at least (since the id is random anyway) set the name attribute of the input fields. Unfortunately, the documentation of `InputElement.setName` says...

> Don't use this method if your
>   application is purely based on ZK's
>   event-driven model.

So, big question: Will this cause somehow troubles if I use this method? Or is there another way to put the name of the input element into the resulting html?

Answer (score 1):

I think the warning in the API is meant to tell you, that ZK does not consider this attribute except of setting it into the rendered html.
Maybe it's there to prevent developers from using `name` instead of ZK's `id` property and thus failing to correctly bind components.

I never encountered a problem when using it.